# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test

Tags: java, maven

Estou iniciando em programação e esse é meu primeiro projeto. Quando executo o "Maven Install", ocorre o seguinte erro **"Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test"**
Preciso de ajuda para resolver

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.seguro</groupId>
    <artifactId>Seguro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SeguroVeicular</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Console

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< br.com.seguro:Seguro >------------------------
[INFO] Building SeguroVeicular 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ Seguro ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ Seguro ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ Seguro ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\Seguro-master\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Seguro ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ Seguro ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests
19:42:47.011 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
19:42:47.118 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
19:42:47.245 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
19:42:47.350 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
19:42:47.377 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests]: class path resource [br/com/seguro/seguroveicular/SeguroVeicularApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
19:42:47.378 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests]: class path resource [br/com/seguro/seguroveicular/SeguroVeicularApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
19:42:47.379 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
19:42:47.379 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests]: SeguroVeicularApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
19:42:47.600 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.327 s <<< FAILURE! - in br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests
[ERROR] br.com.seguro.seguroveicular.SeguroVeicularApplicationTests  Time elapsed: 1.325 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   SeguroVeicularApplicationTests » IllegalState Unable to find a @SpringBootConf...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  24.621 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-10T19:42:48-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project Seguro: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\Seguro-master\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Esse erro é apenas na tua classe de teste, ou seja,  tu não implementou quaisquer tipo de teste. A prova disso é no próprio console, onde a mensagem é: `There are test failures`.
Neste caso, tu pode usar o comando `mvn clean install -DskipTests` que irá pular os testes ou implementar os testes de fato.